# Allowing users in Django app to use same form to create two objects

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am trying to create a simple, Django-based To-do web app. Each task in the app will be linked to tags.

I can achieve the above by creating models for both the tasks and the tags with many:many relationship. When I create the form for user to create new tasks (using ModelForm), they are also offered up a a way to multi-select tags.

All of the above is fine. However, I am trying to figure out a way

1. to give the user the ability to ‘create’ new tags when they’re creating new tasks as well.
2. Ability for user to enter comma separated tags that get added to db as individual ‘tag’ objects.
3. Can this also be done while retaining the choice for users to select from existing tags?

How do I achieve any or all of this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1- you need a button like + in django admin when user click on that show dropdown or something and get tags from user and update your tag list in the tasks form ( with ajax or something else )

2- i think this is can archieve with frontend  search for select2 library.
But if you want user send tag1, tag2, tag3 you can use `.split(",")` in your view to get each tag and save on db.